# How to structure a global chat in Firebase Realtime?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have a global chat that allows any can see what everyone has typed, their name and icon. I have 2 approaches in mind on how to structure the data but I'm not sure which one of these is the best in terms of data cost.

1. First approach:

   `root
     chat
       messageId
         userName
         userIcon
         text`
2. Second approach:

   `root
     chat
        messageId
          userId
          text`

   `root
      profiles
         userId
            name
            icon`

With second approach, I then fetch the userId in a public profiles node that contains all users' names and icons. Which one is should I go for?

Comment: I would go (did go) the second approach.

Comment: @GrahamD My concern with the second approach was it would cost too high, but with a little more research I know now that it only costs one child node in the profiles tree since I already the path to that specific child node.